# How to zoom past 1:1433 with OpenLayers plugin in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.6

I am editing the polygon shapefile in QGIS 2.6 with the projection of "USA_Contiguous_Equidistant_Conic" but I am not able to zoom in the OpenLayers like Google Maps and Bing maps more than 1:1433 scale in QGIS 2.6. I verified it after installed "Tile Map Scale Plugin" as well, but still I can't able to zoom in.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?